# Netsuite Custom Sublist Saved Search Filtered by Free-Form Text Field?

Tags: netsuite, sublist, saved-searches

I am familiar with creating custom sublists on NetSuite forms by creating a Saved Search and on the Available Filters subtab, adding at least one available filter from a List/Record type field.  If you don't use a List/Record type field as the first Available Filter, the saved search is not available to assign as a sublist.

Is there a workaround to add a save search as a custom sublist filtered by a Free-Form text field?  Is there a way to achieve this using SuiteScrpt?  Specifically, I want to use the otherrefnum field on sales transactions to filter a search that shows all other transactions with that otherrefnum.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saved search as custom list can be added to a form only with a List/Record field, since this is the Primary/Foreign key that the join is based on.

I think that the only way to add a saved search sublist that will be filtered by a free-form text is via a script.

You can do it by manually performing the search and generating the sublist on the beforeLoad of the relevant user event.

Just keep in mind that performing searches that are filtered by free text are very heavy and might have significant impact on performance and the loading time of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I can create a saved search and make it a sublist and search on OtherRefNum

In the search definition add criteria to filter to the mainline.
For the available filters select PO/Check ID

go to a customer and select that search for the sublist view.
here's the bug: Now refresh the page and your filter is available.

The results are automatically filtered to transactions for that customer.

If you are trying to make a general search for OtherRefNum do you know that you can just enter it into Netsuite's global search (top of the page) and all transactions that have that value will be returned?

There is no speed penalty for doing a free text search on otherrefnum. It is an indexed field and searches on it are very fast.